# MySQL Many to Many Query. Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, many-to-many, specifications, product

Here's my problem: I have three tables that represent a many to many relationship which look like to following:

**table products**
product_id
product_price, etc. (basic info same for every product)

**table specifications**
spec_id
spec_name

**table products_specifications**
product_id
spec_id
content

My goal is to select products by their specifications (one as well as multiple) so I used the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products p
JOIN products_specifications ps ON ps.products_id = p.products_id
JOIN specifications s ON s.spec_id = ps.spec_id
WHERE s.spec_name IN (<names of specs>)
AND pts.content IN (<content of specs>)
GROUP BY p.products_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.specifications_name) = <count of specs name>
AND COUNT(DISTINCT ps.content) = <count of specs content>
```

I would like to get ALL of the specifications that belong to ALL products, however this query only returns one of the specifications (one that is used to make the query).

The specifications.content column contains the values that I want to use to query a product (or multiple) with (included with all it's specifications). The name of these specifications can be found specifications.spec_name table. To make sure the query does not retrieve content that is possibly the same in another row but from a different specification I also do a WHERE IN of the names of the specifications.

Is it possible make a query that selects on certain specifications, but also returns ALL specifications of the selected product?

I have thought of and experimented with UNIONS and SUBQUERIES. However I wasn't able to produce a query that sufficed. I think a subquery is probably the direction to go in. A second query with the returned product_id is not a possiblity, because it has to be possible to order the query by ANY of the specifications belonging of each product.

Comment: The test using product_specifications.content in your proposed query is confusing me. Let me rephrase your goal and tell me if this is what you want the query to do: Start with a set of one or more values of specifications.spec_name. Find all the rows in products that link to rows in specifications with those values. For each of those rows in products, output all of the rows in product_specifications and specifications linked to it. Please tell me if that is correct, or if not, clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: The specifications.content contain the values that I want to use to query a product (or multiple) with (included with all it's specifications). The name of these specifications can be found specifications.spec_name table. I hope this makes it somewhat clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems correct. It will return all products' details for those products that match your criteria (they are realted to all `(<names of specs>)` and all `(<content of specs>)`). It would be better to use `SELECT p.*` by the way, since you are grouping by `p.products_id`. The results you get from the other columns are not really useful.

Now, if you want to get these products and in addition, get all specifications for these products (not only the spcs that are in your two lists), use this:

(**update:** Added `GROUP BY pd.products_id` and `GROUP_CONCAT()` to gather info for a product from many rows into one)

```
SELECT pd.*
     , GROUP_CONCAT( ps.content
                     ORDER BY ps.spec_id )
     , GROUP_CONCAT( s.spec_name 
                     ORDER BY ps.spec_id )
     , GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(s.spec_name,'-',ps.content)
                     ORDER BY ps.spec_id )
FROM
    ( SELECT p.*
      FROM products p
      JOIN products_specifications ps ON ps.products_id = p.products_id
      JOIN specifications s ON s.spec_id = ps.spec_id
      WHERE s.spec_name IN (<names of specs>)
      AND ps.content IN (<content of specs>)
      GROUP BY p.products_id
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.specifications_name) = <count of specs name>
      AND COUNT(DISTINCT ps.content) = <count of specs content>
    ) AS pd
  JOIN
    products_specifications ps ON ps.products_id = pd.products_id
  JOIN
    specifications s ON s.spec_id = ps.spec_id  
GROUP BY pd.products_id
```

Comment: Ok this is more like it! However it's stil not exactly what want (if that's even possible). It now returns all specifications of a product, however not in one row per product, but it returns every product times(*) the amount of specifications this product has. I tried to add GROUP BY pd.products_id at the end of the query but this results in it only returning one specification (the first)

Comment: @Ruben: See my edit. You have to gather the info with `GROUP_CONCAT()` in that case.

Comment: Very nice ypercube, thanks for your valuable help. This solutions is great, however I have one final question. It is not possible to order the returned results by one of the specs, right?

Comment: @Ruben: what do you mean? Show first the products that have a spec and then those that don't?

Comment: Or do you mean the order inside the GROUP_CONCAT ?

Comment: I mean the order of the total query, so changing the order of the returned data ordered by a spec. I'm assuming this isn't possible since it's concatted into a single "column". Sorting on price is possible because it's not a value that is concatted, but in the products table (See my first post).

Comment: You can have in the `ORDER BY` clause, whatever can be in the `SELECT` list. So, every column of the `product` table is fine. Any aggregate result like the `GROUP_CONCAT()`s is fine too. You could have `ORDER BY COUNT(*)` (number of specs).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM products_specifications
GROUP BY product_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for you contribution, but I'm not doing the query by product_id, but by product_specifications.content. I edited my question a bit, hopefully it's somewhat clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely clear on what you are trying to do, but if I can restate your goal: you would like to select "products" with a given "specification", but for those "products" select all their "specifications".  Have you tried joining on the "products_specifications" and "specifications" tables twice like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
JOIN product_specifications ps1 ON ps1.products_id = p.products_id
JOIN specifications s1 ON s1.spec_id = ps1.spec_id
JOIN product_specifications ps2 ON ps2.products_id = p.products_id
JOIN specifications s2 ON s2.spec_id = ps2.spec_id
WHERE s.spec_name IN (<names of specs>)
AND pts.content IN (<content of specs>)
GROUP BY p.products_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT s.specifications_name) = <count of specs name>
AND COUNT(DISTINCT pts.content) = <count of specs content>
```

Note the s1 & s2, and ps1 & ps2.  The s1 & ps1 will allow you to select, but you can see all using s2 & ps2.  Also you had 'pts' in your `WHERE` clause, but didn't specify it as a table in your `FROM` section, I assume you intended 'ps'?

Comment: I clarified my question a bit better. Your query returns false because of the table aliases of the conditional part of the query. So if I correct this then I have to choose one of the JOIN set (1 or 2) and end up with the same result

Answer (score 0):

With your clarification, Ruben, I think I understand the database structure and what you are asking now. I will start with the observation that what you need to use to query the database is one or more **pairs** of specifications.spec_name and products_specifications.content. As you state in your question, you want to be able to use one or more of these to query for a set of products that meets all of the conditions.

To see why only the pairwise combination of spec_name and content is reasonable, consider an example where the products are cars and some of the specifications are the colors of various components (e.g. body_color, interior_color, racing_stripe_color). If you search for cars with body color red and interior color black, but the query does not associate spec_name and content in pairs, then you will also retrieve cars with body color black and interior color red, which isn't what you want. Same thing applies if any of your specifications have numbers as values.

My answer uses a subquery to return the product_id values that will be used to generate the final output, but it could also be done with additional joins. If the query using subquery is too slow, you may need to try the other version. I'm also going to use "select *", although I would strongly recommend against doing that in a production environment (you should list the columns instead), since things tend to break much more easily if there is a change in the database structure. You also will get some columns with duplicate values that could be eliminated by a proper listing of columns. I am assuming that product_id and spec_id are unique in the products and specifications tables, respectively, and that each combination of product_id and spec_id occurs at most once in the products_specifications table.

```
select * from (
    select p1.product_id as product_id from products as p1
    join products_specifications as ps1 on p1.product_id = ps1.product_id
    join specifications as s1 on ps1.spec_id = s1.spec_id
    where <selection conditions>
    group by p1.product_id
    having count(s1.spec_id) = <number of selection conditions>
    ) pp 
join products as p on pp.product_id = p.product_id
join products_specifications as ps on p.product_id = ps.product_id
join specifications as s on ps.spec_id = s.spec_id
order by p.product_id, s.spec_name;
```

The <selection conditions> will be in the form:

```
   (s1.spec_name = 'spec1' and ps1.content = 'spec1value')
or (s1.spec_name = 'spec2' and ps1.content = 'spec2value')
or ...
```

for as many spec_name, content pairs as you want to use in the query. You will need to generate that part of the query either by hand or in the calling code. You will need to make sure that <number of selection conditions> equals the number of conditions in the same way.